# Is there a way to streamline canvas code

Tags: javascript, mysql, canvas, svg

This is a bit of a strange issue but I have a world map that is produced from lines of canvas code.

The canvas code is derived from an SVG file that was automatically converted by a website but it produced 47000 lines of code & a 1.5mb file size.

This obviously takes some time to load and occasionally it doesn't appear (it currently resides in a .js file that is remote loaded).

Is there a way to streamline this code to reduce the file size.

I have thought about transferring all the line coordinates into a sql table and producing it that way but I'm not sure if that would be any better.

Example code:

```
function world(scale) {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(scale,scale);

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(39960,0);
ctx.lineTo(39960,19980);
ctx.lineTo(0,19980);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.lineCap = "butt";
ctx.lineJoin = "miter";
ctx.miterLimit = 4;
ctx.save();
ctx.restore();
ctx.save();
ctx.restore();
ctx.save();

ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#bcbcbc";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.lineWidth = 5.5;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.miterLimit = 4;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(14553,0);
ctx.lineTo(14528,2);
ctx.lineTo(14502,2);
ctx.lineTo(14476,2);
ctx.lineTo(14448,4);
ctx.lineTo(14464,17);
ctx.lineTo(14436,15);
ctx.lineTo(14413,11);
ctx.lineTo(14395,4);
```

Comment: Have you tried minifying the file?

Comment: Could you post a small example of that canvas code file?  You mention your file is lines of canvas code.  Often, maps are represented as a series of lines.  If your file actually contain the context.lineTo(100,100) commands you can certainly eliminate all but the actual data (100,100) and your filesize will be cut in half.  You can rehydrate the full command in JS on the client-side.

Comment: maybe just zipping the file is the quick-and-dirty-and-efficient-enough way to go...

Comment: I've added the example - certainly just using the coordinates might make a difference

Comment: The minified code is still 960kb

Comment: Yep, you can strip out the "command" part of each line and your file size will be cut in half.  Then rehydrate on the client-side.  For example that last batch could be re-written "svg-ish": BP M:14553,0 L:14528,2 14502,2 14476,2 14448,4 14464,17 14436,15 14413,11 14395,4 which costs 82 characters instead of 146. Similarly, code like: ctx.lineCap = "round" can be tokenized: LCR.
 BTW, the converted code has some kruft: ctx.save()/ctx.restore() with nothing in-between does nothing useful.  Likely more kruft elsewhere.

Comment: You can use [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) to render SVG on canvas in real time. When fetching SVG, make sure server transfers it gzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        function CanvasProxy(target){

    var Host=new Object;

    for (var v in target)
        switch (typeof target[v]) {
        case "function":Host[v]=addMethod.bind(v);break;
        case "number":setProperty(v);break;
        case "string":setProperty(v);break;
        case "object":Host[v]=target[v];break;
        default:setSimpleProperty(v)
        };

    return Host;

    function addMethod(){
        var ret=target[this].apply(target,arguments);
        if (typeof ret==="undefined") return Host;
        Host[this]=target[this];
        return ret;
    }

    function setProperty(p){
        function property(v){target[p]=v;return Host;}
        property.toString=property.valueOf=function(){return target[p]}
        Object.defineProperty(Host, p , {get : function(){return property}, set : function(v){ target[p] = v}});
    }

    function setSimpleProperty(p){
        Object.defineProperty(Host, p , {get : function(){return target[p]}, set : function(v){ target[p] = v}});
    }

    }

var ctx;
function _init(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = CanvasProxy(canvas.getContext("2d"));
}

function world(scale) {

ctx.scale(scale,scale)
.save()
.beginPath()
.moveTo(0,0)
.lineTo(39960,0)
.lineTo(39960,19980)
.lineTo(0,19980)
.closePath()
.clip()
.strokeStyle("#ffffff")
.lineCap("butt")
.lineJoin("miter")
.miterLimit(4)
.save().restore().save().restore().save().save().fillStyle("#bcbcbc").....
```